# How do I make a simple counting loop in Swift?

Tags: loops, swift2

I am using Swift 2.0 and I am trying to make a simple app with a counter. So every time I press a button, the count of a label is supposed to go up one by one. I cannot figure out how to make this kind of loop. I have been really confused about this because Xcode tells me strings and integers do not go together. What should happen is when I press the button, the String will change from 1 to 2, then if I press it again it will go from 2 to 3. So could you give some examples of how to do this? Please help me and give a bit explanations of how it works and why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a tutorial site. You should be able to find other material on the internet from where you can learn the basics of Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an internal counter and an ibaction

```
var counter : Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var PlusButton : UIButton?
@IBOutlet weak var Numbertoshow : UILabel?


@IBAction func UseCurrentLoc(sender: UIButton) {
    counter++
    Numbertoshow!.text="\(counter)"

}
```